# Select the first row returned by CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, coalesce

This is for SQL Server. I have a query that's trying to find the total balance in an account at a certain point in time (30 days before most recent transaction date, 90 days before most recent transaction date, etc). The table I'm querying keeps 'snapshots' of account balances over time with the amount and the time in which the transaction occurred.

| PERSON | TOTALBALANCE | RCNTTRANS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | $5000 | 6/1/2021 |
| Sarah | $4500 | 9/29/2021 |
| Sarah | $7000 | 11/30/2021 |
| Joe | $90 | 1/5/2020 |
| Joe | $8000 | 1/17/2020 |
| Joe | $2100 | 2/28/2021 |

I figured I could use a case statement to get the total balance at any date less than the most recent transaction date minus however many days away I'm looking for. However, this returns a row for every previous RCNTTRANS date. Is there a way to select only the first row that's returned?

```sql
SELECT 
    ,T.PERSON
    ,CASE WHEN T.TRANSACTIONDATE <= DATEADD(DAY, -30, T.RCNTTRANS) THEN T.TOTALBALANCE ELSE 0 END AS TEST
    ,CASE WHEN T.TRANSACTIONDATE <= DATEADD(DAY, -90, T.RCNTTRANS) THEN T.TOTALBALANCE ELSE 0 END AS TEST2
    ,CASE WHEN T.TRANSACTIONDATE <= DATEADD(DAY, -180, T.RCNTTRANS) THEN T.TOTALBALANCE ELSE 0 END AS TEST3
FROM #TEMP T
```

I tried COALESCE, but that didn't seem to work. I also tried FIRST_VALUE, but that didn't seem to work either. I could possibly have been using them incorrectly, though.

**Expected Results**

| PERSON | TEST1 | TEST2 | TEST3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | $4500 | $5000 | NULL |
| Joe | $8000 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Rather than using the current balance column, can you not just `SUM(CASE WHEN etc THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS balance` to sum all the transactions prior to the cut-off in each case? It's a little difficult to tell. Please post the full schema of your transactions table.

Comment: Right, add the sample data for `TRANSACTIONDATE` as well, and show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate and `SUM` each `CASE WHEN`, and within date ranges.

> ```
> create table #TEMP (
>  PERSON VARCHAR(30), 
>  TOTALBALANCE MONEY, 
>  RCNTTRANS DATE
> )
>
> insert into #TEMP (PERSON, TOTALBALANCE, RCNTTRANS) values
> ('Sarah',     $5000,  '2021-11-29'), 
> ('Sarah',     $4500,  '2021-12-01'), 
> ('Sarah',     $7000,  '2021-12-30'), 
> ('Joe',   $90,    '2020-08-28'), 
> ('Joe',   $8000,  '2021-02-01'), 
> ('Joe',   $2100,  '2021-02-28');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT T.PERSON
> , SUM(
>  CASE 
>  WHEN T.RCNTTRANS >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, M.TRANSACTIONDATE) 
>   AND T.RCNTTRANS <  M.TRANSACTIONDATE
>  THEN T.TOTALBALANCE END) AS BALANCE1
> , SUM(
>  CASE 
>  WHEN T.RCNTTRANS >= DATEADD(DAY, -60, M.TRANSACTIONDATE) 
>   AND T.RCNTTRANS <  DATEADD(DAY, -30, M.TRANSACTIONDATE) 
>  THEN T.TOTALBALANCE END) AS BALANCE2
> , SUM(
>  CASE 
>  WHEN T.RCNTTRANS >= DATEADD(DAY, -180, M.TRANSACTIONDATE) 
>   AND T.RCNTTRANS <  DATEADD(DAY, -60, M.TRANSACTIONDATE) 
>  THEN T.TOTALBALANCE END) AS BALANCE3
> FROM #TEMP T
> LEFT JOIN (
>   SELECT PERSON, MAX(RCNTTRANS) AS TRANSACTIONDATE
>   FROM #TEMP
>   GROUP BY PERSON
> ) M ON M.PERSON = T.PERSON
> GROUP BY T.PERSON
> ORDER BY T.PERSON DESC;
> ```

> 

| PERSON | BALANCE1 | BALANCE2 | BALANCE3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | 4500.0000 | 5000.0000 | *null* |
| Joe | 8000.0000 | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5434cc3e1e1a4c8cff51af1f11326e35)*

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TMP;

CREATE TABLE #TMP (
    PERSON VARCHAR(30), 
    TOTALBALANCE MONEY, 
    RCNTTRANS DATE
)

INSERT INTO #TMP (PERSON, TOTALBALANCE, RCNTTRANS) VALUES
('Sarah',   $5000,  '2021-01-06'), 
('Sarah',   $4500,  '2021-09-29'), 
('Sarah',   $7000,  '2021-11-30'), 
('Joe',     $90,    '2020-01-05'), 
('Joe',     $8000,  '2020-01-17'), 
('Joe',     $2100,  '2021-02-28');

DECLARE @TRANSACTIONDATE DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(2022,1,29); -- FOR TESTING

WITH CTE_BasicData
AS(
    SELECT 
        T.PERSON, 
        T.TOTALBALANCE, 
        T.RCNTTRANS,
        DATEDIFF(day, @TRANSACTIONDATE, T.RCNTTRANS) AS [DAYS],
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @TRANSACTIONDATE, T.RCNTTRANS) <= -180 THEN '180 days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @TRANSACTIONDATE, T.RCNTTRANS) <= -90 THEN '90 days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @TRANSACTIONDATE, T.RCNTTRANS) <= -30 THEN '30 days'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS [Period]
    FROM #TMP AS T
)

,CTE_Data
AS(
    SELECT 
        d.PERSON, 
        d.TOTALBALANCE, 
        d.RCNTTRANS,
        d.[DAYS],
        d.[Period],
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY d.PERSON, d.[Period] ORDER BY d.[DAYS] DESC) AS [Ranking]
    FROM CTE_BasicData AS d
)

,CTE_Pivot
AS(
    SELECT 
         P.[PERSON]
        ,P.[30 days]
        ,P.[90 days]
        ,P.[180 days]
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            d.PERSON, 
            d.TOTALBALANCE, 
            d.RCNTTRANS,
            d.[DAYS],
            d.[Period]
        FROM CTE_Data AS d
        WHERE (1=1)
            AND d.Ranking = 1
    ) AS D
    PIVOT(SUM(D.TOTALBALANCE) FOR D.[Period] IN([30 days],[90 days],[180 days])) AS P
)

--SELECT * FROM CTE_Data ORDER BY PERSON, RCNTTRANS; RETURN;
--SELECT * FROM CTE_Pivot ORDER BY PERSON; RETURN;

SELECT
     d.[PERSON]
    ,SUM(d.[30 days]) AS [30 days]
    ,SUM(d.[90 days]) AS [90 days]
    ,SUM(d.[180 days]) AS [180 days]
FROM CTE_Pivot AS d
GROUP BY
    d.[PERSON]
```